# R fails to install packages, at load stage, under linuxmint (Ubuntu)

Tags: r

I am trying to install package 'RcppEigen' to my installation of R version 3.3.1 on my 64-bit Intel PC running LinuxMint 17.1, which I understand is essentially the same as Ubuntu trusty, as far as R is concerned. The installation always fails at the 'load' stage. I get the same errors when I try to install package 'lme4', which is the package I actually want. RcppEigen is a dependency, on which the lme4 installation fails.

The error messages say it cannot find packages 'lapack' and 'blas'. I've done some searching and found some threads that say I should either set up some symbolic links to the missing files, or copy them somewhere, but it's not clear to me which files those are, other than that they probably have 'lapack' and 'blas' somewhere in their names.

Here is the command I issued, from the R command line.

> install.packages('RcppEigen')

And here is the output, with error messages.:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/andrew/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RcppEigen_0.3.2.9.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 1209128 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘RcppEigen’ ...
** package ‘RcppEigen’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/andrew/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppEigen.cpp -o RcppEigen.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/andrew/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/andrew/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o RcppEigen.so RcppEigen.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR

<HERE COME THE ERROR MESSAGES. THIS BRACKET MANUALLY INSERTED BY Andrew>

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RcppEigen.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/home/andrew/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RcppEigen’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
   ‘/tmp/RtmpI463VA/downloaded_packages’
```

I would be very grateful for any suggestions anybody can make about how to make this installation work.

Thank you

Here is my system info

```
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                     
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.1                         
year           2016                       
month          06                         
day            21                         
svn rev        70800                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
nickname       Bug in Your Hair
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly:

1. You can install RcppEigen as a binary: `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcppeigen`.  There are several hundred core CRAN packages ...
2. The error messages `cannot find -llapack` and `cannot find -lblas` indicate that you have the *run-time* environment but the development headers / packages.  Easiest fix: do `sudo install r-base-dev` and try again.

Either approach should work. If all else fails consider coming to the r-sig-debian list for help with R on Debian-based systems.

Comment: Thank you very much Dirk. I'd been fiddling around with this for hours yesterday, including upgrading R (which was a major headache getting that done in its own right), and getting solutions from all over the net that didn't work. Your suggestion (I used 1) solved it in one quick command line instruction. I am very grateful.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Installation of R itself should also be a breeze (if you can run Ubuntu binaries).  I run multiple machines at work and home -- and `apt-get` delivers current binaries off the CRAN mirrors, see https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: Oh, and do 2) as well.  You pretty much _must have_ the `r-base-dev` package to ensure required dependencies.

Comment: Thank you Dirk. I have now run (2).